# Alertmanager v0.25 inhibit rule

Tags: devops, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am running kube-prometheus-stack 43.3.0 which includes Alertmanager 0.25 on a k8s cluster.

My alertmanager config yaml looks like this:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1alpha1
kind: AlertmanagerConfig
metadata:
  name: alertmanager-test-config
  namespace: monitoring
  labels:
    alertmanagerConfig: test
spec:
  receivers:
  - name: console-test
    webhookConfigs:
    - url: "https://hidden.com/health/k8s_register"
  - name: k8s-node-down
    webhookConfigs:
    - url: "https://hidden.com/health/k8s_register_node_crash"
      sendResolved: true
  route:
    groupInterval: 5m
    groupWait: 10s
    receiver: all_alerts
    repeatInterval: 3h
    routes: 
      - matchers:
        - name: severity
          value: "report"
        receiver: console-test
        continue: true
      - matchers:
        - name: severity
          value: "k8s-node-down"
        receiver: k8s-node-down
        continue: true
      - matchers: 
        - matchType: =~
          name: severity
          value: "report|k8s-node-down"
        receiver: all_alerts
```

Alerts:

```
    - alert: CoreDown
      expr: hidden_core_total < 0
      for: 5m      
      labels:
        severity: report
        namespace: "{{`{{ $labels.instance }}`}}"
      annotations:
        summary: "Core is down on {{`{{ $labels.instance }}`}}"
        module: "core"
        instance: "{{`{{ $labels.instance }}`}}"
```

```
    - alert: K8SNodeDown
      expr: kube_node_status_condition{condition="Ready",status="false"} == 1
      for: 5m
      labels:
        cluster_name: clusterName
        severity: k8s-node-down
      annotations:
        node: "{{`{{ $labels.node }}`}}"
        module: "node down"
        summary: "Kubernetes Node Down"
        description: "Kubernetes node {{`{{ $labels.node }}`}} is down."
        cluster_name: {{ .Values.clusterName | replace "-k8s" "" }}
```

I am trying to add an inhibition rule so that `severity: report` alerts would be inhibited when `severity: k8s-node-down` is ongoing.

Following the Prometheus docs and also the kube-prometheus-stack values.yaml example, I tried adding the rule in multiple ways, but it still does not show up in my alertmanager config file (which is a CRD).

What I tried:

Adding the following code directly inside my alertmanager CRD object:

```
  inhibitRules:
    - sourceMatch:
        severity: "k8s-node-down"
      targetMatch:
        severity: "report"
      equal: []
```

Result:

```
spec:
  inhibitRules:
    - equal: []
```

I also tried adding the rule to kube-prometheus-stack values.yaml:

```
alertmanager:
  config:
    global:
      resolve_timeout: 5m
    inhibit_rules:
      - source_matchers:
          - 'severity = k8s-node-down'
        target_matchers:
          - 'severity = report'
        equal:
          - 'test'
```

Result: nothing gets added to the config file.

Can you help me find out what am I missing?